# pgfplotstable: Adding a style in one row

Tags: pgfplotstable

[image]

I want to add a `\cdot` in each cell in the row 'Multiplier'.

*· Note that the main-code could have more columns! 

· Note that the values 'results' are calculated in the main code; but not in this MWE.*

It seems, that `every row no  2/.append style ={...}` only allows commands like `before row=\hline`, `after row=...`

But how to add a style in one row correctly?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstablenew[
create on use/Names/.style={create col/set list={Binarydigit No.,Binarydigit,Multiplier,results}},
columns={Names}
]{7}\modulotable

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/set list={2,1,10,10}]{2}\modulotable
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/set list={1,0,1,1}]{1}\modulotable
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/set list={0,1,10,10}]{0}\modulotable

\pgfplotstableset{
mydot/.style={
postproc cell content/.append style={/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={$\cdot}{$}},
},
}

\noindent\pgfplotstabletypeset[
%every row no  2/.append style = {mydot}, % works not
every row 2 column 1/.append style={mydot},% works partially
columns/Names/.style={string type, column type=l},
]\modulotable
\end{document}
```